# C, finding the index of the character

Tags: c

Alright, so what I have to do is find the index of the first character of a word. Here, a word is only consisted of alphabet and nothing else.

Right now, I'm having trouble in placing my fgetc or ftell() pointer to where it has to be.

For example, in an arbitrary string "A Greatest America, 2014 is the",
it will find correct index of

```
'A': 0, 
'Greatest': 2, 
'America': 11,
```

but for 'is', which is the next word, it will display 18 (correct would be 25).
Then after for word 'the', it will display correct index of it again.

I know that the problem is my nextword() method returns when it hits space and sets the wordPos whenever it does hit one, but I cannot figure out a way to identify "not-words" like 2014 and move over to the next proper word.

Here is the code that I have written.

```
#define MAXWORD 200
char word[MAXWORD];
int wordLength;
int wordCount;
int charCount;
int wordPos;

// A word is a sequence of alphabetical characters.
static char * nextword(FILE * fd) {
    unsigned int c;
    wordLength = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fd)) != -1){      
        if (c != EOF && c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\r'){
            if (isalpha(c)) 
                word[wordLength++] = c;
        }
        else{
            word[wordLength] = '\0';

            if (wordLength == 0)
                continue;       
            return word;
        }
    }
    if (wordLength > 0){
        word[wordLength] = '\0';

        return word;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }

}

// Conver string to lower case
void toLower(char *s) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++){
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
}


// Read a file and obtain words and positions of the words and save them in table.
int wtable_createFromFile(WordTable * wtable, char * fileName, int verbose)
{
    char *w;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fd = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fd != NULL){
        wordPos = 0;
        while ((w = nextword(fd)) != NULL){
            toLower(w);
            wtable_add(wtable, w, wordPos);
            if(verbose)
                printf("%d: word=%s, pos=%d\n", i++, w, wordPos);
            wordPos = ftell(fd);
        }
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: How can `unsigned int c` equal `EOF` which is typically `-1`? Aside: try to avoid magic numbers, `'A'` and `'Z'` and `'a'` and `'z'` are portable and more readable.

Comment: In `nextword` function, at the beginning of the while add a condition, `if (c!='A' || c!='z' || c!='a' || c!='z')`

Comment: Consider using [`isalpha()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt82b8z8.aspx).

Comment: isalpha() works, I've changed the condition to it. Phantom: it didn't work. :(

Comment: @WeatherVane `unsigned int c` can easily equal `EOF` as the comparison converts `EOF` to `unsigned` in the same way as `c = fgetc(fd))`.  Although confusing and better to use `int c;`  `c != EOF`, itself, is not the problem.

Comment: @chux yes my little test showed that it can. That is, the code can make it so, as the standard allows, to make nonsense usable. But `-1` is definitely not `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux they are edited

Comment: wordPos = ftell(fd) specifies where the file position is after return from nextword(). What if the string started with spaces or tabs? wordPos would be the wrong position, correct? what happens with skipping ,2014?

Comment: `wordLength = 0;` does not compile as `wordLength` is not declared, neither is `toLower()`, `WordTable`, `wtable_add()`  and maybe others.  Post true code and without line numbers.

Comment: `if (isalpha(c)){  wordPos = ftell(fd);/* word end position */ word[wordLength++] = c;  }` ... `printf("%d: word=%s, pos=%d\n", i++, w, wordPos-wordLength);` But It's not a good approach. Because `ftell` can not be applied to text mode files in this way.

Comment: Please don't post code with embedded line numbers - it means no-one else can paste it into (say) an editor and try to compile it.

Comment: "I know that the problem is my nextword()" is not certain. AFAIK, unposted `wtable_add()` is killing the data.  With first post and 2 edits and still lacking a  complete compilable code to demo the problem, the problem remains unnecessarily difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for word boundaries and words are made only of letters, the only thing you really need to be checking for is whether something is a letter.  Instead of checking for whitespace, treat *everything* that's not a character exactly like whitespace.  You should be able to simplify your `nextword` function to something like:

```
int c;
wordLength = 0;

while ((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF)
{
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        // Letters get added to the buffer
        word[wordLength++] = tolower(c);
    }
    else
    {
        // A non-letter signifies the end of the current
        //  word, unless we haven't seen any letters yet.
        if (wordLength > 0)
            break;
    }
}

if (wordLength == 0)
    return NULL;

// Terminate string and return
word[wordLength] = '\0';
return word;
```

I can't test this since your posted sample isn't enough to compile, but hopefully it will move you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop having just one if-then-else will cover all cases:

```
if (isalpha(c)) {
    word[wordLength++] = c;
} else if (wordLength != 0) {
    word[wordLength] = '\0';
    return word;
} else {
    wordPos++;
}
```

This ensures that wordPos progresses at non-letters.

Either use still ftell or

```
wordPos += wordLength;
```

Nicer code is imaginable, so let's await other answers.